# Error with Restlet sample project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, restlet

I downloaded the [sample Restlet project](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/304-restlet.html) and opened it in Eclipse. I instantly get this error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Google WebApp Project Validator' on project 'org.restlet.example.serialization.gae-gwt'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same error with my own project. In the Eclipse Project Explorer I right-clicked the project and chose Refresh. That cleared up the error for me.

Comment: Close projects and restart eclipse. - http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2013/02/errors-running-builder-google-webapp.html

Answer (score 4):

This is a temporary, but repeatable solution someone on my team found...

Close project
Close Eclipse
Open Eclipse
Open project

Comment: close projects and re-open eclipse using ./eclipse -clean

Answer (score 1):

I continually had this problem in combination with git. My git repository was in my eclipse workspace ( even though eclipse warns you not to do this ). Deleting the old repository, and creating a new git repository outside of the eclipse workspace, then cloning a fresh copy of my gwt project solved this problem for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also experiencing this error, but thanks to git comparing .classpath I noticed that I had removed a couple of variables from the "Configure Variables" list, but not from the Java Build Path. Once I removed it from the second list, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was using a workspace that was on an NFS and I had the same workspace open on two different vnc sessions. I closed out Eclipse on one vnc session and then restarted eclipse on the other. Then I went to the java build path and editted the gwt sdk and had it use the gwt sdk it was already pointed to and it stopped giving me that error. I didn't actually change the gwt sdk, just went through the motions of doing so. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was miss configuration of JRE, I just did the following:
Go to Build path configuration, select add Library, JRE System Library, select your JRE.
And there you go...

Answer (score 0):

For me this error seemed to occur after a compile had failed due to lack of memory and eclipse had been restarted. However, after increasing memory (in the eclipse.ini) the problem still persisted. None of the above solutions worked for me.

The bizarre solution I found: our project here uses GWT 2.4, so I switched to 2.5 (which comes with the plugin - window>preferences>google>Web Tookit), re-compiled, switched back to 2.4 and, hey presto, it worked again!

(Another hour of my life I'll never get back!)